# Detecting TabMove in firefox add-on

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Tried out the impl. given in : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Notification when a tab is added or removed

for tracking 'tabmove'. Didn't work.

Would appreciate any help in this regard.

BTW, already tried below code. Only 'TabOpen' event is received. 'TabClose' and 'TabMove' does not work:

```
var browserWindows = require("sdk/windows").browserWindows;
var activeWindow = browserWindows ? browserWindows.activeWindow : {};
var browserWindow = activeWindow ? require("sdk/view/core").viewFor(activeWindow) : {};
var DOMWindow = browserWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);

var exampleTabAdded = function(event) {
 var browser = DOMWindow.gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(event.target);
 console.log('tab added: '+ event.target);
};
var exampleTabMoved = function(event) {
 var browser = DOMWindow.gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(event.target);
 console.log('tab moved: '+ event.target);
};

function exampleTabRemoved(event) {
  var browser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(event.target);
  console.log('tab removed: '+ event.target);
}


function exampleTabSelected(event) {
  var browser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(event.target);
  console.log('tab selected: '+ event.target);
}

var container = DOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer;
container.addEventListener("TabMove", exampleTabMoved, false);
container.addEventListener("TabOpen", exampleTabAdded, false);
container.addEventListener("TabClose", exampleTabRemoved, false);
container.addEventListener("TabSelect", exampleTabSelected, false);
```

Thanks

Comment: That's an xul event, it won't work from sdk without tapping into the xul. Let me check if sdk has equivalent event. edit: there doesnt seem to be one, lets wait to see if the sdk experts have any input on this, otherwise ill show you how to tap into the xul

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. i wouldn't mind using xul within add-on.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. Uses both sdk api's as well as XUL content document.
If there is a better way to handle 'tabmove', please do post the answer.

```html
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var { modelFor } = require("sdk/model/core");
var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");
var tab_utils = require("sdk/tabs/utils");

var contentDocumentMap = new Map();

function mapHighLevelTabToLowLevelContentDocument(tab) {
 var lowLevelTab = viewFor(tab);
 var browser = tab_utils.getBrowserForTab(lowLevelTab);
 return browser.contentDocument;
}

function onOpen(tab) {
 tab.on("pageshow", logShow);
 tab.on("activate", logActivate);
 tab.on("deactivate", logDeactivate);
 tab.on("close", logClose);
}

function logShow(tab) {
 var contentWindow = mapHighLevelTabToLowLevelContentDocument(tab);
 if ((contentWindow.URL === 'about:newtab') || (contentWindow.URL === 'about:blank')) {
  return;
 }
 if (contentDocumentMap.has(contentWindow)) {
  return;
 }
 contentDocumentMap.set(contentWindow, tab.id.toString());
}

function logActivate(tab) {
 var contentWindow = mapHighLevelTabToLowLevelContentDocument(tab);
 if ((contentWindow.URL === 'about:newtab') || (contentWindow.URL === 'about:blank')) {
  return;
 }

 if (contentDocumentMap.has(contentWindow)) {
  return;
 }
 contentDocumentMap.set(contentWindow, tab.id.toString());
}

function logDeactivate(tab) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  var windows = require("sdk/windows").browserWindows;
  for (let window of windows) {
   var activeTabContentWindow = mapHighLevelTabToLowLevelContentDocument(window.tabs.activeTab);
   var activeTabId = window.tabs.activeTab.id.toString();
   if ((contentDocumentMap.has(activeTabContentWindow)) && (contentDocumentMap.get(activeTabContentWindow) !== activeTabId)) {
    console.log('M O V E D. url: '+ window.tabs.activeTab.url);
    console.log('from tabid: '+ contentDocumentMap.get(activeTabContentWindow) + ' to tabid: ' + activeTabId);
    contentDocumentMap.delete(activeTabContentWindow);
    contentDocumentMap.set(activeTabContentWindow, activeTabId);
   }
  }
 }, 150);
}



function logClose(tab) {
 var targetTabId = tab.id.toString();
 setTimeout(function() {
  var windows = require("sdk/windows").browserWindows;
  for (let window of windows) {
   var activeTabContentWindow = mapHighLevelTabToLowLevelContentDocument(window.tabs.activeTab);
   var activeTabId = window.tabs.activeTab.id.toString();
   if (contentDocumentMap.has(activeTabContentWindow)) {
    if (contentDocumentMap.get(activeTabContentWindow) !== activeTabId) {
     console.log('M O V E D. url: '+ window.tabs.activeTab.url);
     console.log('from tabid: '+ contentDocumentMap.get(activeTabContentWindow) + ' to tabid: ' + activeTabId);
     contentDocumentMap.delete(activeTabContentWindow);
     contentDocumentMap.set(activeTabContentWindow, activeTabId);
    }
    else if (targetTabId === activeTabId){
     contentDocumentMap.delete(activeTabContentWindow);
    }
   }
  }
 }, 150);
}

tabs.on('open', onOpen);
```

Comment: Awesome job there! Very interesting way to do it without using XUL.